# The code our Teacher gave us has an error in it. It's on the line public class MyArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>

Tags: java, arrays

The code my Teacher gave me has an error in it. I get this error on `MyArrayList`:

> Duplicate methods named spliterator with the parameters () and () are
>   inherited from the types Collection and Iterable

Why does it not work for me but it works for other students?

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E> 
{
private E[] data_store = (E[])new Object[50];
private int how_many = 0;
```

Comment: Which error you talking about

Comment: Could you post the full source code of your class ?

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/a63375405ea1bb7312e9a1fe99b72c31.png

Comment: The whole code is too long so I'll post another gyazo.
http://i.gyazo.com/d09189945f1843fa435166c1083a3b90.png

Comment: You may be trying to compile Java 7 code with a Java 8 JDK. Check what Java version the code was compiled with.

Comment: @Jacket : Edit your code with the link to the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of is the mismatch of Java version that the code was compiled with what you have setup in your environment.

Another reason could be that you are using an older version of IDE that does not support Java 8. For example, eclipse versions prior to Luna do not fully support Java 8 (Others correct me here if I got my facts wrong).